# Creating multiple threads for same method on an instance on an object

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a question.  Is it possible and valid, if I have an object with a method DoSomething(), if I create multiple threads for this method, will it work and would it run as a seperate thread of its own?

E.g.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //somethings done here
    }
}

public class MainProgram
{
    public MainProgram()
    {
         InitializeComponents();
    }

    protected override OnStart(string[] args)
    {
         SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
         Thread workerOne = new Thread(() => sc.DoSomething());
         workerOne.Start();

         Thread workerTwo = new Thread(() => sc.DoSomething());
         workerTwo.Start(); //start a new thread calling same method
    }
}
```

I hope that kind of explains what I mean.  Would this work or cause any problems?

I am writing a program that needs to almost be realtime software, I am currently deciding whether initialising a new instance of SomeClass is better or not?

Hope someone can answer.  If my question's dont make sense, please comment and I'll explain further!

Thanks,

Base33

PS The code was written specifically for the example :)

Comment: what version of c# / .NET are you on?

Comment: Obligatory link: [Joe Albahari's free ebook](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

Comment: I am a Java programmer. But after taking a closer look at your code, it seems that you can reuse the same instance of SomeClass. Although, only one thread will be able to run the method while the other waits for its turn. Atleast that is what happens in Java.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Each thread has a separate call stack, so *yes* they can both be using the same method on the same object. And indeed, if needed each thread can (via recursion) call the same method on the same instance *multiple times* if you really want.

However, what *might* trip you up is if you are using **state** in that object (instance or static fields, etc, and anything related *from* that state). You will need to ensure your access to any shared state gives full consideration (and presumably synchronisation) to multi-threaded access.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do that. You will however have to make sure that your member accesses within that method are thread safe.

If you mutate the state of the object you should either lock your reads and writes (not speaking of any particular mechanism) or verify that it's harmless to interupt the method at any given time and that the other call on a different thread will still work correctly

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible and valid, if I have an object with a method DoSomething(), if I create multiple threads for this method, will it work and would it run as a seperate thread of its own?

Yes it is possible.  In your code example, `DoSomething` is being called on the same instance of `SomeClass`.  Both threads share this.  You have two distinct threads but one actual object being shared.

> Would this work or cause any problems?

That entirely depends on your use case.  It may or may not.  If objects are shared, you need to synchronize access to them.

Answer (score 1):

It has no problem. I will run without any error.

> It is just like creating an object and call method on this object
>   twice. only fact is that two occurrence of calling same method is on
>   different thread.